# How to calculate composition of alcohol/water mixture to achieve given concentration of alcohol vapors in air for calibrating a DIY breathalyzer?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solutions, gas-laws, alcohols, sensor

I made a breathalyzer using a MiCS-5524 gas sensor. I would like to calibrate it so it can be close to accurate. [e2v technologies — MiCS Application Note 4, Using MiCS Sensors for Alcohol Detection (PDF)](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/3199/AN4-Using-MiCS-Sensors-for-Alcohol-Detection.pdf) shows a method of heating an alcohol/water solution and testing the air that has been bubbled through the mixture.

If I was to heat a liter of alcohol/water solution to 37 °C, what ratio of alcohol to water would I need to make the air have 10 ppm of alcohol? I don't have much experience with chemistry so please keep that in mind when you explain the solution.

Comment: Now this is a case where experimenting on humans does not sound inhumane. Why not use your body as a test input?

Comment: @IvanNeretin Human bodies are difficult to be adjusted to produce breath with 10 ppm of ethanol. :-)  Unless evaluated side by side by the DIY and commercial tester. Then the particular ethanol content is not important.

Comment: I've done that already to see if it detects alcohol on my breath but its still hard to calculate a fairly precise ppm by just drinking some booze and blowing after a half hour. I was hoping to get a more precise read out so it'll work on persons of different heights and weights.